# Tracking a server side redirect in Google Analytics

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics

There is a URL say http://www.example.com/redir.php?p=http://www.google.com This URL will be linked directly in other sites/documents. This page just redirect you to a 3rd party site. I want to track visit to this redirect page.

Ideally I want to create a server side redirect by setting HTTP location header since it will be more user friendly. If it is not possible I am also open to client side redirect using meta-refresh or something like that.

So is it possible to do a server side redirect while tracking it at the same time or do I have to opt for client side redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you're looking for is the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). This allows you to send data directly from your server to Google's servers.

But be warned, open redirects aren't a good idea: [OWASP Open Redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect).

Comment: Thanks for help and tip about Open Redirects. I am currently using only pre-defined aliases. I just used open redirect only for the example